# How to simulate touch on Image Button using view client

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

can any one tell me how to simulate touch on Image Button using android view client python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is using **[culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/culebra)**:

```
$ culebra -VC -o myscript.py
```

Then, edit `myscript.py` and search for your ImageView, it might be something like

```
# class=android.widget.ImageView
no_id20 = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("id/no_id/20")
```

and add

```
no_id20.touch()
```

save the edited script and run it.

```
$ ./myscript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Image_button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //Do your implementation
        }
    });
```